# Getting syntax errors when creating function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have been spending over 2 hours now trying to google my way to the answer.

I am completely new to SQL and MySQL and I have tried to write the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fp_spinofffactor (id char(8), startdate date)
RETURNS float
BEGIN
DECLARE spinoffFactor float;               (ERROR- EXPECTED A ";")
select spinoffFactor = ISNULL(EXP(SUM(LOG(spinoffFactor))),1)
from( 
select case when (prev_price- divs) <= 0 THEN 1 
else (prev_price- divs)/prev_price end as spinoffFactor
    from (select
    divs,
    fp_v2.fp_prevUnadjPrice(id, ex_date) as prev_price
from (
select sum(fbd.p_divs_pd) as divs,fbd.p_divs_exdate as ex_date
from fp_v2.fp_basic_dividends fbd
where fbd.fsym_id = id
and fbd.p_divs_s_pd=1
and fbd.p_divs_exdate > startdate
group by fbd.p_divs_exdate ) a ) b ) c; 
return spinofffactor;              ERROR (Return is not valid at this position)
END                                ERROR (END IS NOT VALID AT THIS position)
```

But I get multiple syntax errors. I have written the errors where I get them.

I have a hard time finding information about the syntax rules of MySQL and the workbench.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide delimiter in MySql workbench to tell where your code begins and ends. 
Assuming your syntax is correct, you can write as below.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fp_spinofffactor (id char(8), startdate date)
RETURNS float
BEGIN
DECLARE spinoffFactor float;       
    select spinoffFactor = ISNULL(EXP(SUM(LOG(spinoffFactor))),1)
    from( 
    select case when (prev_price- divs) <= 0 THEN 1 
    else (prev_price- divs)/prev_price end as spinoffFactor
        from (select
        divs,
        fp_v2.fp_prevUnadjPrice(id, ex_date) as prev_price
    from (
    select sum(fbd.p_divs_pd) as divs,fbd.p_divs_exdate as ex_date
    from fp_v2.fp_basic_dividends fbd
    where fbd.fsym_id = id
    and fbd.p_divs_s_pd=1
    and fbd.p_divs_exdate > startdate
    group by fbd.p_divs_exdate ) a ) b ) c; 
return spinofffactor;              
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can also, run this from MySQL command prompt and it should work.

Comment: Thanks man. Do you have 5 minutes for private chat? I have a few questions.

Comment: @Chris, glad it worked. I do not use chat and only try to help, when get time. If you have any specific questions, you can post again and someone will take a look. Have a good day.